# Can I trick Shotwell into recognizing my SD card if it doesn't automatically?

Tags: sd-card, shotwell

Well, since Ubuntu 15.10 my Shotwell doesn't recognize SD cards anymore, and [I reported a bug for that](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759875). I know I can `Import from folder...` but that doesn't quite offer the same functionality.

Is there any way I can trick Shotwell into accepting my SD card? Like, marking a folder as a camera manually? Or a disk?

**Technical Information**
I'm pretty confident my Shotwell comes from [this daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ubuntu/daily-builds), and `shotwell -V` says `Shotwell 0.22.0`.
The SD card in question is `/dev/mmcblk0`. Then `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` says

```
NAME        FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT                 LABEL
mmcblk0             29.5G                              
└─mmcblk0p1 vfat    29.5G /media/.../NIKON D71006    NIKON D7100
```

I use my camera (Nikon D7100) to format the SD card. There seems to be a 4.2MB section of unallocated space at the beginning of the card. *Edit: Another card without the unallocated space produces the same behavior, so it doesn't matter.*